# Divide array based on inner array conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like :

```
let colors=[ [ 31236780195925 ],[],[],[],[],[ 31236780163157 ],[],[],[ 31236780228693 ],[],[],[],[],[] ]
```

inner array values can differ, 
I want result like in the following structure

```
let Red=[[ 31236780195925 ],[],[],[],[]];
let Green=[[ 31236780163157 ],[],[]];
let Blue=[[ 31236780228693 ],[],[],[],[],[]];
```

Comment: Based on what are you splitting up the array?

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: from one value contain inner array to next  value contain inner array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution. It checks length of each element and if it becomes more then 0 it starts to fill next index. `Red` has `[0]` index, `Green` has `[1]` index, `Blue` has `[2]` index of resultant array.

```js
var colors=[ [31236780195925],[],[],[],[],[ 31236780163157 ],[],[],[ 31236780228693 ],[],[],[],[],[] ];

var res_ar = []; 
var i = -1;
 
colors.forEach(ar => {
      if (ar.length > 0) {
        i++;
        res_ar.push([]);
      }
        res_ar[i].push(ar); 
})

  // console.log(res_ar) 

console.log(res_ar[0]);
console.log(res_ar[1]);
console.log(res_ar[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented it using `reduce` and `destructuring`:

```
const [R, G, B] = colors.reduce((acc, cur, indx) => {
    if(cur.length && indx === 0 ) {
        acc.push([cur]);
    } else if(!cur.length) {
        acc[acc.length - 1].push(cur);
    } else {
        acc.push([cur]);
    }

return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to extract an RGB value, and thus have 3 values in your colors array. You could do something like this:

```
const colors = [[31236780195925], [], [], [], [], [31236780163157], [], [], [31236780228693], [], [], [], [], []];
const indexes = [];

colors.forEach((color, index) => {
    if (color.length > 0) {
        indexes.push(index);
    }
});

const red = colors.slice(indexes[0], indexes[1]);
const green = colors.slice(indexes[1], indexes[2]);
const blue = colors.slice(indexes[2]);
```

- The first loop creates an array of indexes of every array in your `colors` variable which isn't empty.
- You can then `.slice` your array at those indexes to split them apart.

---

In case you want a more dynamic approach. You could loop over your colors array again and use those indexes to create a new nested array:

```
const slicedColors = [];

colors.forEach((color, index) => {
    if (color.length > 0) {
        const nextColorIndex = indexes[indexes.indexOf(index) + 1];
        slicedColors.push(colors.slice(index, nextColorIndex));
    }
});

const red = slicedColors[0];
const green = slicedColors[1];
const blue = slicedColors[2];
```